# Problem in Cocos2d

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I downloaded **"cocos2s iphone-1.0.0-rc"** and **"cocos2d 1.0.0 beta template foe Xcode4"**
and copy them to **'/developer/Library/Xcode/Templates '** then open xcode and click on
new project ans see add 3more types of project (cocos2d,cocos2d-box2d,cocos2d-chipmunk)
and i create a project with cocos2d and doesn't add any code to it and run it but occur 6 errors,3 warnings in class 'CCTexture2D.m':

> Font Manager undeclared  ()
>
> Assigning to 'CGSize'(aka struct
>   CGSize)from incompatible type id
>
> method -sizeWithZfont not found
>
> NSSTring may not respond to
>   'sizeWithZFont'
>
> Incompatible types in assignment
>
> Method 'drawInRectWithZfont' not found

i open Link binary With Libraries and can't find Cocos2d from list
and i add #import "cocos2d.h" in prefix.pch but doesn't work

Please help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you installed cocos2d with the terminal, like this?

> Run the 'install-templates.sh' script:

```
$ cd cocos2d-iphone
$ ./install-templates.sh -u -f
```

Comment: i do it but after i push Enter nothing happen just come new line is it ok ? and after i do it again occur errors